# UINavigation Bar Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi
i am using sdk4.2 version
in my app at first the navigation bar and the whole design perfect when m going forward side of run. but when i press back button of navigation controller the whole design go down by 48pixel. it create 48 pixel gap between navigation and content.
what's the problem? i don't know m facing first time.
even am use ViewDidAppear method to set do not hidden navigaion bar.

Comment: provide some sample code how you create this view

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that  **setTranslucent** is set as NO in all classes. As shown below:

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

Comment: it's not the problem navigation bar is visible at all time. the problem is when m press back button the view shift 48 pixel down.means view shows navigation bar o to 48 and then a blank space of 48 to 96 pixel. then the view is shown after 96 to onwards...